# Unable to generate classname.g.dart class using freezed package

Tags: flutter, freezed

I have a freezed class that looks like this:

```
@freezed
abstract class GiftGiver with _$GiftGiver {
  const factory GiftGiver({
    String? id,
    String? uid,
    String? imageUrl,
    String? giftDetails,
    String? listingDate,
    @Default(5) int listingFor,
    Timestamp? pickUpTime,
    @Default(false) canLeaveOutside,
  }) = _GiftGiver;

  factory GiftGiver.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$GiftGiverFromJson(json);
}
```

The freezed class is generated fine but .g.dart class is not generated as I have Timestamp type. I saw some solution at https://github.com/rrousselGit/freezed#fromjson---classes-with-multiple-constructors but I am not understanding how to apply it to solve my problem.

Comment: Can you provide the code for Timestamp? Does it have its own 'fromJson' method? That's required

Comment: Timestamp is a default Firebase class. I looked inside the class there were no toJson and fromJson. But I found a solution using JsonKey annotation.

Comment: Ah I see now. That's the correct solution in that case, good job

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you need to add the `json_serializable` package in the `dev_dependencies` section in the `pubspec.yaml` file.

If this is your case, delete the `pubspeck.lock` file, and then run the command `flutter pub get` to generate the file `pubspeck.lock` again.

Then, run the command `flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs and fix` to generate the `.g` file

Comment: `flutter packages pub run build_runner watch --delete-conflicting-outputs` also try using `watch`

Answer (score 3):

After some research I found out the solution. For types that are not supported by **JsonSerializable** I needed to use **JsonKey** to create my own **toJson** and **fromJson** method. I am attaching one such class that has **Timestamp** and Also another nested class (**MyPosition**) inside it.

```
@freezed
class GiftGiver with _$GiftGiver {
  const factory GiftGiver({
    String? id,
    required String uid,
    required String imageUrl,
    required String giftDetails,
    required String listingDate,
    required int listingFor,
    @JsonKey(fromJson: _pickedTimeFromJson, toJson: _pickedTimeToJson)
        required Timestamp pickUpTime,
    required bool canLeaveOutside,
    @JsonKey(fromJson: _fromJson, toJson: _toJson) required MyPosition position,
  }) = _GiftGiver;

  factory GiftGiver.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$GiftGiverFromJson(json);
}

Map<String, dynamic> _toJson(MyPosition myPosition) => myPosition.toJson();
MyPosition _fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MyPosition.fromJson(json);

Timestamp _pickedTimeToJson(Timestamp pickUpTime) => pickUpTime;
Timestamp _pickedTimeFromJson(Timestamp json) => json;
```

GiftGiver class uses MyPosition (another Freezed class) which looks like this =>

```
@freezed
class MyPosition with _$MyPosition {
  const factory MyPosition({
    required String geohash,
    @JsonKey(fromJson: _geoPointFromJson, toJson: _geoPointToJson)
        required GeoPoint geopoint,
  }) = _MyPosition;

  factory MyPosition.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$MyPositionFromJson(json);
}

GeoPoint _geoPointToJson(GeoPoint geoPoint) => geoPoint;
GeoPoint _geoPointFromJson(GeoPoint json) => json;
```

To use **MyPosition** in **GiftGiver** properly I needed to create **_toJson** and **_fromJson** and tell GIftGiver how to decode and encode MyPosition field.

Comment: It is supposed it must be done by the builder itself!

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, you need this:

```yaml
dependencies:
  # ...
  json_annotation: ^4.8.1
```

and

```yaml
dev_dependencies:
  # ...
  freezed: ^2.3.4
  json_serializable: ^6.7.0
```

If not mistaken you need `json_serializable` for the `.g.dart` file to be generated. When I added that it generated the needed file.

I think that is used for the `fromJson` factory method.